# Changing Context ClassLoader while running

Tags: java, multithreading

Can I change the context class loader of a thread, while the thread is running, e.g. setting the context inside the `run()` function?

I've searched via Google for an answer, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  What program feature are you attempting to offer by 'changing class-loaders'?

Comment: Actually, i don't know. I saw it in an existing code, and before investigate the goals of that piece of code, I thought that it might be illegal....

Answer (score 2):

You can use Thread.setContextClassLoader() if your security manager allows it.  You have to very careful as you can get very confusing results and the error message you tend to get are not always helpful.

I would suggest you start a new thread with a different class loader.

Comment: so... i can change the context class loader inside the run() function? is it legal? now on the thread will load classes in the new class loader, although when it was created it loaded classes with different class loader?

Comment: BTW, i don't need any advide; it is not code i wrote. i just want to know if its legal.

Comment: Its legal but tricky to get right this way IMHO.  If it happens to work, I wouldn't worry about it so much.  If you get strange cast errors, this could be a cause.